# What's the consistency strength of resemblance + global failure of the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, continuum-hypothesis

Let $T$ be a theory formalized in first order logic with equality and membership and the additional primitive constant symbol $W$, with the following axioms:

1. **Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$
2. **Class comprehension:** if $\phi$ is a formula in which $x$ doesn't occur free, then all closures of: $$\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi \land  \exists z (y \in z) ) $$; are axioms.

   Define: $x=V \iff \forall y (\exists z (y \in z) \to y \in x)$
3. **Sub-world:** $W \in V$
4. **Resemblance:** if $\varphi^X$ is a formula in prenex normal form, whose matrix is in $L(=,\in)$, and each variable in its prefix must appear as bounded either $\in X$ or $\subseteq X$, then:  $$\varphi^V \leftrightarrow \varphi^W $$, is an axiom.
5. All axioms of "$\sf ZF + \text {CH fails everywhere}"$ relativized to $W$.

> What's the consistency strength of $T$?

Comment: Why do you keep asking this question?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, that's the first time I asked this question. I never asked about the effect of resemblance on global failure of choice.

Comment: Zuhair, I think @Monroe means that a lot of your questions are quite similar: take a theory, vary some axiom scheme, ask for consistency strength. To a professional set theorist, these questions are kind of odd. We don't see the picture in your head that motivates this sort of research, and at some point it starts to become repetitive for no good reason. We know that you're a hobbyist, and I think it's great people are interested in this on a hobbyist level. But seeing how this is not what set theorists normally do, seeing a continuous flow of these questions is just... befuddling.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm interested in axiomatics for their own sake, not for a motivation the lies prior to them (like capturing an informal notion, construction, etc...), the motivation of an axiomatic system is itself, so I only need to know its relative consistency to other axiomatics, and see what it can bear. That is hobby, but it doesn't mean that it is not serious. I want to investigate these various axiomatics, especially those that are connected to recombination of known axiomatic systems, since otherwise there is endless axiomatics. Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila for example here in this question, I want to know how far can resemblance go! Can it add strength to something that is known to be stronger than it, which is failure of continuum hypothesis everywhere; can indescribability (what resemblance is about) on top of failure of CH everywhere also yield stronger results? or it becomes idle at such altitude? I expect such a question to be easy for a professional set theorist interested in large cardinals to answer.

Comment: Based on the fact that among your last 30 questions only 8 received an answer and you get +6 summing all of their up and downvotes, the other users of the website don't appear to be interested in such questions for their own sake. As Asaf was saying those theories appear arbitrary/unmotivated, usually set theorists start by studying a problem interesting by itself which then turns out to have high consistency strength, they don't sit around randomly modifying axioms until they stumble in an interesting one. Of course you can ask any question, but if you never get answers you should wonder why

Comment: It seems that you are just imagining different axiom systems and telling us about them, while putting the question, "What is the consistency strength?" at the end to justify these being mathoverflow questions.  I think this is not an appropriate use of mathoverflow, because it is not really about posing and solving mathematical problems.  Moreover, "What is the consistency strength?" is not in general a well-defined question because the set of all theories is not linearly ordered or well-founded in the relative consistency partial order.

Comment: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/1998-August/001929.html

Comment: @MonroeEskew, No! I'm asking about the consistency strength to find if it is consistent or not, and to see in which of the known systems it is equi-interpretable. For example here I'm asking specifically about whether resemblance would increase the strength of failure of CH everywhere when added on top of it? This is a question. My aim is not to show you an axiomatic system as you think, its not really a hard job to come up with such axiomatics, I'm presenting that problem axiomatically in order for it to be presented it in rigorous terms, and I think that's how it should be presented.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking about regular cardinals